# Why am I able to query a remote database without a dblink?

Tags: oracle, security, dblink

While researching a security concern, I discovered that users are able to query a remote database without the need of a dblink.

However, this was only true for databases that had no value for `DB_DOMAIN`. If the **local** database's `DB_DOMAIN` was qualified with "foo.com", then a user could **not** query the **remote** DB and required a dblink.

I could not find any documentation that explains why this happens and am a very new DBA. What is it about Oracle that allows this to happen? Is the only way to prevent this to qualify every database's `DB_DOMAIN` with "foo.com"?

Example of accessing information from remote DB without a dblink below:

**From DB: FooB**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Thu Feb 26 16:05:21 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show parameter db_domain;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_domain                            string
```

**From DB:FooA**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Thu Feb 26 16:08:25 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> show parameter db_domain;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------------------
db_domain                            string
SQL> select sysdate from dual@FooB;

SYSDATE
---------
26-FEB-15


SQL> select db_link from all_db_links;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64693/discussion-on-question-by-exit-1-why-am-i-able-to-query-a-remote-database-withou).

Answer (score 2):

What you described here is absolutely normal and intended. This feature is called a **global** database link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/ds_concepts002.htm#i1007888

It is a "side effect" when for example Oracle Internet Directory is in use, I have seen this at a few companies who have a lot of databases.

More and better explanation can be found in the support note: **What are Global Database Link and How do you Disable them? (Doc ID 1632329.1)**

> You are able to make a distributed connection using a Database link,
>   However you have not created the database link used.
>
> You expect an ORA-2019 since the Database link Object itself does not
>   exist but somehow the connection works. How is this possible?
>
> This is because of a default feature Called GLOBAL DATABASE LINKS. The
>   feature is due to LDAP usage.
>
> Global Database links were introduced in earlier versions of Oracle
>   when the Oracle Names Server was in use. You could create a Database
>   Link that was stored in the Oracle Names server and accessed by those
>   who accessed the Oracle Names Server. Once Oracle Names was deprecated
>   the feature was moved to the replacement LDAP Naming.
>
> When a Database link is called the database link name will be checked
>   against the PRIVATE link then PUBLIC links then GLOBAL links. **If the
>   Database link name matches the entry listed in the ldap server the
>   actual Database link object is not required. The DBLINK will use the
>   current user to connect therefore it only works if the user has access
>   to both instances and has the same user id and same password on both.**
>
> This is default behavior when LDAP naming is used.
>
> Currently the only way to disable the feature is to stop using LDAP
>   naming.

Answer (score 1):

I now see that Balasz has provided a solution, too. My solution works if the name of the database is FooB, and I see now that that isn't the case here. So Balas will be right. But I leave this post because it seems not to be widely known that this works.

---

From Administrator's Guide, [31 Distributed Database Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_concepts.htm#ADMIN13493),

> **Global Name as a Loopback Database Link**
>   You can use the global name of a database as a loopback database link without explicitly creating a database link. When the database link in a SQL statement matches the global name of the current database, the database link is effectively ignored.
>
> For example, assume the global name of a database is `db1.example.com`. You can run the following SQL statement on this database:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM hr.employees@db1.example.com;
> ```
>
> In this case, the `@db1.example.com` portion of the SQL statement is effectively ignored.

---

If a directory service is in use (ldap server) [global database link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_concepts.htm#i1007827) can be defined network wide outside of the database.

> No user owns the global database link. The global database link exists in a directory service.